# Impact when - awaiting the async method which does not have any await calls

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have a following async method which does not have any await calls.

```
public async Task<bool> AddCust(Customer cust)
    {
    // doing some synchronous operations
    return true;           
    }
```

Following method calls the above method and await for the result.

```
public async Task<bool> ParentMethod(Customer cust)
{
 var result = await AddCust(cust);
 if(!result)
       // some logic
 return true;
}
```

Here the caller, await for the AddCust to return the 
Now, question is if I keep the above code as it is would it be any negative impact on performance? if yes, why?

Comment: Suspect an XY problem. Why would you want to do this? Note that the compiler will give you a warning, because the code is almost certainly the wrong solution for whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use a profiler to check if there's any significant performance hit.

At the end of the day, `await` is a compilation detail (also called *syntactic sugar*!) which compiles the code into regular TAP code (Task-Asynchronous Pattern).

BTW, your code could be easily rewritten to:

```
public Task<bool> AddCust(Customer cust)
{
    // If you need to perform sync operations and you also want to 
    // retain an asynchronous TAP-based method signature you should
    // go this way.

    return Task.FromResult(true);           
}
```

Finally, you should rename your async method and add the `Async` suffix. For example, `AddCustAsync`, since it's the naming convention. If some developer checks your code he/she will think it's a synchronous operation until he/she realizes that it returns a `Task`...

## IL comparison

I've implemented your case and I got the resulting IL.

Actually you can check how `Task.FromResult` version has less IL code lines than the `async` counterpart:

#### Without `async`

```
A.Test1:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  call        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // CS$1$0000
IL_0008:  br.s        IL_000A
IL_000A:  ldloc.0     // CS$1$0000
IL_000B:  ret
```

#### With `async`

```
A.Test2:
IL_0000:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_0002:  ldarg.0     
IL_0003:  stfld       UserQuery+A+<Test2>d__0.<>4__this
IL_0008:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_000A:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Boolean>.Create
IL_000F:  stfld       UserQuery+A+<Test2>d__0.<>t__builder
IL_0014:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_0016:  ldc.i4.m1   
IL_0017:  stfld       UserQuery+A+<Test2>d__0.<>1__state
IL_001C:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_001E:  ldfld       UserQuery+A+<Test2>d__0.<>t__builder
IL_0023:  stloc.2     
IL_0024:  ldloca.s    02 
IL_0026:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_0028:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Boolean>.Start
IL_002D:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_002F:  ldflda      UserQuery+A+<Test2>d__0.<>t__builder
IL_0034:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Boolean>.get_Task
IL_0039:  stloc.1     
IL_003A:  br.s        IL_003C
IL_003C:  ldloc.1     
IL_003D:  ret
```

There should be no *big* performance hit, but maybe if you go the `async` way when there's no need to simplify the code because there's no async operation being called in the method body, you're adding extra compilation and run-time overhead that can be avoided using the `Task.FromResult` approach...

Comment: Is there any advantage to writing the code that way, aside from getting the compiler warning not to show up

Comment: @SamIam I doubt there's an objective advantage. BTW, why adding compilation overhead if you can avoid it? `Task.FromResult<T>` is meant to be used in your scenario after all...

Comment: @SamIam I can't confirm it, but I suspect that `async/await` with no async operation maybe compiles `Task.FromResult` anyway... It's about checkinfg what's actually compiled using IL Dissassembler, Reflector or whatever :D

Comment: @SamIam Check my answer update about the resulting IL... it seems like the `async` approach could be avoided if you don't execute async operations... :)

Comment: Keep in mind that exception behavior is different under both approaches.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski So it seems like `Task.FromResult` is simpler than the `await` approach in terms of understanding how exception handling works......

Comment: @Matías it's different... If you use `async` and your method throws, the exception will be wrapped in the returned `Task`, as expected from the async pattern. If you use `Task.FromResult` the exception will be thrown as usual.

Comment: So, Implementing the Task.FromResult and awaiting in the caller will not cause any performance issues? What would be the negative impact as compared to making a method itself as synchronous(removing Task from return statement)?

Comment: @PratikMehta Uhhhhhhhh you're very wrong. Async/await doesn't convert an async method into sync!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: no, I meant If I change my above code
1) To return simply bool insted of async Task<bool> (so that making method synchronous and remove await from the caller)
OR
2) Change the method to return Task<bool>  (adding the TaskFromResult while returning value and remove async from the method signature)

What is the performance impact if I use second approach(as I am not awaiting anything)

Comment: @PratikMehta First of all, you should use a profiler!!! In the other hand, if your option is making the method 100% synchronous and you don't expect to perform hard work in the whole method, why not? This could be the best solution...

Comment: @PratikMehta BTW, honestly you're trying to optimize this and is a waste of time. This won't be your bottleneck in your software...............